# AWS service's textract method "getDocumentTextDetection" is only returning "JobStatus" and nothing else in response

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-textract

I am trying to textract the pdf file with aws-sdk's service Textract.getDocumentTextDetection In which I am passing JobId returned by method "startDocumentTextDetection".

Here first I am trying to upload the image/pdf by using s3 service's method "upload" which is successfully running and returning me response like this

```
{ 
  ETag: '"9d022c9c496f2663d2fgv45d181e475"',
  Location:
   'https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/beacon-logo.png',
  key: 'beacon-logo.png',
  Key: 'beacon-logo.png',
  Bucket: 'bucket-name' 
}
```

After this I am calling textract's method "startDocumentTextDetection" to get the JobId, which is returning me this:

```
{ JobId:
   '11df404ce0fa7c958ba23579890a52388132a01d326802a1eggh76915c55qw1e' }
```

After this I am calling AWS service's another method "getDocumentTextDetection" to extract words from uploaded file which is returning me object:

```
{ JobStatus: 'IN_PROGRESS' }
```

which is wrong.
The method "getDocumentTextDetection" should return something like this:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/API_GetDocumentTextDetection.html

And below is all the code till written till now:

```
const textract = new AWS.Textract({
  apiVersion: "2018-06-27",
  accessKeyId: "my-access-key-id",
  secretAccessKey: "my-secret-access-key",
  region: "region",
  ACL: "public-read"
});

const s3 = new AWS.S3();

router.post("/", function (req, res, next) {
  const paramsS3Upload = {
    Bucket: "bucket-name",
    Key: req.files.document.name,
    ACL: "public-read",
    ContentType: req.files.document.mimetype,
    Body: req.files.document.data
  };
  var s3options = {
    partSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024,
    queueSize: 1
  };
  s3.upload(paramsS3Upload, s3options, function (s3Err, s3data) {
    if (s3Err) throw s3Err;
    var params = {
      DocumentLocation: {
        S3Object: {
          Bucket: s3data.Bucket,
          Name: s3data.Key,
          Version: s3data.VersionId
        }
      },
      NotificationChannel: {
        RoleArn: "arn:aws:iam::id:role/role-name",
        SNSTopicArn: "arn:aws:sns:region:id:topic-name"
      }
    };
    textract.startDocumentTextDetection(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
      else {
        var textDetectionParams = {
          JobId: data.JobId
        };
        textract.getDocumentTextDetection(textDetectionParams, function (
          err,
          textDetectData
        ) {
          if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
          else {
            console.log(textDetectData); // Not getting proper response here!!
            res.send({
              data: textDetectData
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

The expected output should be like this:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/API_GetDocumentTextDetection.html. Not able to figureout whats going wrong.

Comment: Seems like the text detection is not finished yet when calling `getDocumentTextDetection`, from the doc : _When the text detection operation finishes, Amazon Textract publishes a completion status to the Amazon Simple Notification Service (Amazon SNS) topic that's registered in the initial call to StartDocumentTextDetection. To get the results of the text-detection operation, **first check that the status value published to the Amazon SNS topic is SUCCEEDED**. **If so**, call GetDocumentTextDetection, and pass the job identifier (JobId) from the initial call to StartDocumentTextDetection._

Comment: I recommend you to use an SNS to get notified when the job is done. Then you can use a Lambda function to continue with your job

Comment: I am also getting the same issue

Comment: I'm getting same issue, it should be 'SUCCEEDED' but always came IN_PROGRESS, so I must wait for a sns message with SUCCEEDED to process and it's wrong and expensive in a lambda function.